# Issue with cookie, cookie is lost after closing browser

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've created a cookie like below and can retrieve all `font_size`, `back_color` and `font_name`. But once I close the browser the cookie is lost. From what I know is if we get expiry date wrong cookie can be lost but I've tested the date, `expireGMT` and is fine. Have I done anything wrong in the code below? Do I need to include `path` as well?

```
   document.cookie = "font_size=14";
   document.cookie = "back_color=Gray";
   document.cookie = "font_name=Georgia";
   document.cookie = "expires=" + expireGMT;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each individual write to `document.cookie` is the setting of a cookie, and any options (including that cookie's expiration date) must be set on that write. You need to include the expiring time on every cookie assignment:

```
document.cookie = "font_size=14; expires=" + expireGMT;
document.cookie = "back_color=Gray; expires=" + expireGMT;
document.cookie = "font_name=Georgia; expires=" + expireGMT;
```

without that, each cookie will be created as session cookies and expire when the browser's closed.

Comment: did that but i'm still losing cookie, could it be path? i haven't given path

Comment: Depends on where you're trying to load the cookie from afterwards.

Comment: i'm doing normal stuff: if(indexOf()>=0) //do something with cookie.
Nothing else. Can you point me to some related readables?

Comment: not what/how, but where. I believe default cookie behavior is to set the same path as the script from where the cookie was set. If you're then trying to load this cookie from a higher or parallel path, it'll be effectively invisible.

Comment: okay I had some issues in one of the iteration, thanks for you help Marc B